# configure sidebar to be able to scroll horizontally visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I make sidebar scrollable horizontally? Otherwise long file names can't be seen if I don't increase the sidebar width manually every time I need. Check the screenshot below:

[image: missing horizontal scroll]

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15539

Answer (score 75, accepted):

v1.22 released in April, 2018 has just added the ability to add horizontal scrolling to various tree elements, like the explorer pane.  [Horizontal scrolling support](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_22#_tree-horizontal-scrolling-support).

> // Controls whether trees support horizontal scrolling in the
> workbench.

```
  "workbench.tree.horizontalScrolling": true, (deprecated, don't use)
```

False is the default so you will need to change the setting.  A restart is required.

---

**UPDATE**: vscode **v1.32** just changed the setting to:

```
"workbench.list.horizontalScrolling": true,
```

`Workbench > List: Horizontal Scrolling` in the settings UI.

Comment: I didn't get the updated version yet. My vscode still shows 1.21.

Comment: You might be able to force it with the gear icon / check for updates.  mine came through earlier today.

Comment: I'm running the latest version (1.43.0) on a mac and this setting is still not on by default. I had to manually set it as true.

Comment: Yes, `false` is still the default; the name of the setting changed.

Comment: Oh Praise the lord you have saved me.  Christ that has been plaguing me!!!!

Comment: I would love to know the rationale as to why this would default to false.

Comment: @DLAN the setting page has a warning: _"turning on this setting  has a performance  implication"_. I have no idea why that would be the case (given that anyway horizontal scrolling is there when using it via trackpad instead of a mouse), but that's probably the reason.